# Activity Indicator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to use activity indicator in my app.

I am using to JSON Parsing in my app. first when i click the sync button when ever the data download activity indicator is display & when downloading complete it stop.

Same isuue is here, When app start data is downloadin at that time i also put activity indicator in app.

I am using below methods for connection...

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{

}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

}
```

Comment: So.. you want us to write your code for you?

Comment: When you write "I am using below methods for connection", and all you have are the stubs of the methods, with _no code_...I don't even know what to call it. Disingenuous at best; insulting our intelligence, possibly.

Answer (score 5):

```
 UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
 [indicator setCenter:CGPointMake(YourXPoint, YourYPoint)];
 [self.view addSubview:indicator];
 [indicator startAnimating];
```

and when you want to stop indicator use this

```
  [indicator stopAnimating];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the given below line to start activity indicator visible to user , this line to be used when you start parsing JSON

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=YES;
```

The above line will show the activity indicator on status bar

To stop put the  line in didfinishloading and didfailwitherror methods

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need declare an instance variable of type `UIActivityIndicatorView` in your class. thats the only way to go.

You can initialize it in `viewDidLoad` method.

When you want to make an asycn. call use `startAnimating` on that `activityIndicator` variable and in

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

}
```

You should use `stopAnimation` on your  `activityIndicator` variable.